# How to join to 2 rows of data in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to merge 2 rows of data into 1 row.
I've tried searching on how to do that all i saw was no good.

Here is my sample table

```
ID | Col1    | Col 2
=====================
1  | value11 | value12
2  | value12 | value22
```

This is what i want to achieve

```
ID | Col1    | Col 2   | Col21   | Col22
==========================================
1  | value11 | value12 | value12 | value22
```

Please help... Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you select the 2 rows

Comment: SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE id IN (1,2); here

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do some pivoting. Here's an example that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: what if there more records in your sample table with ID 3,4,5 etc?

Comment: You need to mention the condition on how you're joining the rows. If you have a table with 2 rows and 10 columns, are you expecting 1 row with 20 columns? Will there be other rows in the table?

Comment: What does id mean in the result set?

Answer (score 0):

One of the 100 samples

```
SELECT
 s1.id,
 s1.col1 AS c1,
 s1.col2 AS c2,
 s2.col1 AS c21,
 s2.col2 AS c22 
FROM sample_table AS s1 
LEFT JOIN sample_table AS s2 ON s1.id +1 = s2.id
WHERE s1.id = 1;
```